# C# how to make the stored file to cap at 100 items?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make a small program that take the user input and store it on a file but I want that file to cap at 100 elements:

Let's say the user add 100 names and the next name the user add it will show a message "List is full"

Here is the code I have done so far:

```
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private string SongName, ArtistName;

    public void Registry()
    {
        List<Name> MusicList = new List<Name>(); //Create a List
        MusicList.Add(new Name(SongName = txtSongName.Text, ArtistName = txtArtistName.Text)); //Add new elements to the NameClass

        //check if the input is correct
        if (txtSongName.TextLength < 1 || txtArtistName.TextLength < 1)
        {
            Info info = new Info();
            info.Show();
        }
        else //if input is correct data will be stored
        { 
            //Create a file to store data
            StreamWriter FileSaving = new StreamWriter("MusicList", true);
            for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count; i++)
            {
                string sName = MusicList[i].songName; //Create new variable to hold the name
                string aName = MusicList[i].artistName; //Create new variable to hold the name
                FileSaving.Write(sName + " by "); //Add SongName to the save file
                FileSaving.WriteLine(aName); //Add ArtistName to the save file

            }
            FileSaving.Close();
        }
    }

    private void btnEnter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Registry();
        //Set the textbox to empty so the user can enter new data
        txtArtistName.Text = "";
        txtSongName.Text = "";
    }

    private void btnClose_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

Comment: You stated what you want to achieve and what you've done so far, but forgot to mention what is the problem you are facing, why can't you move forward.

Comment: When you say `show a message "List is full"`, do you mean a messagebox?

Answer (score 3):

```
 private const int MAX_STORED_SONGS = 100;//as class level field


 for (int i = 0; i < MusicList.Count && i < MAX_STORED_SONGS; i++)

 //...after the loop
 if( MusicList.Count > MAX_STORED_SONGS )
    errorMessageLabel.Text = "List is full, only 100 items added"
```

I'm not sure what your list picker looks like, but you would probably want to actually prevent them from selecting more than 100 items, by using some javascript/validation client side before the page is submitted.

What is not clear about your code, is while it appears the user submits a single song, you create a new empty MusicList, add a single item to it, but you loop through it as if there is more than one item.  Perhaps you should begin by reading the file to determine how many songs are in it, so you can determine when it is at 100 songs.

Comment: Go on, be generous. Chuck in a `const int MAX_STORED_SONGS = 100;`

Comment: @MatthewWatson Follow the conventions, PascalCase it!

Comment: @Antonijn I agree.  Studies also show all upper case is harder to read because less than 10% of the words/letters we see are upper case.  However, colleagues I respect as programmers use the all upper convention for constants, and I have always avoided the battle as one not worth fighting.

Comment: Well, they do tend to stand out - they should be pretty rare though.

Answer (score 1):

You may wish to try using xml to give your data some structure.

If you want to keep it in the current format your only option is to count NewLines in your file and see if that count plus any new items in your music list puts you over your limit.

```
List<string> lines = new List<string>(System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(MyFile));
lines.Add(sName + " by " + aName);

int lineCount = lines.Count;
//limit reached
if(lineCount > 100 )
{
    //TODO: overlimit code
} else {
    System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(MyFile, lines.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: +1 It appears you(VoDanh) are using the file like a database.  If they are only adding one file each postback, then you need to read in your file and see how many there are.  If you used a file format that allowed you to read the data back in to your MusicList collection(XML,Json, or comma delimited), then you could use most of your existing code, just begin by populating the MusicList with the data from your file.